# How do I start a COM server? Code is in Python

Tags: python, com, win32com

I want to run Python code as a COM server. Eventually I want to run an RTD server available [here](https://github.com/SublimeText/Pywin32/blob/master/lib/x32/win32com/demos/excelRTDServer.py). But first I want to know what exactly you have to do to getting any COM server running. So let's focus on [this example](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/html/com/win32com/HTML/QuickStartServerCom.html).

```
class HelloWorld:
    _reg_clsid_ = "{7CC9F362-486D-11D1-BB48-0000E838A65F}"

    _reg_desc_ = "Python Test COM Server"

    _reg_progid_ = "Python.TestServer"


    _public_methods_ = ['Hello']

    _public_attrs_ = ['softspace', 'noCalls']

    _readonly_attrs_ = ['noCalls']

    def __init__(self):
        self.softspace = 1
        self.noCalls = 0

    def Hello(self, who):
        self.noCalls = self.noCalls + 1
        # insert "softspace" number of spaces
        return "Hello" + " " * self.softspace + who


if __name__=='__main__':

    import win32com.server.register
    win32com.server.register.UseCommandLine(HelloWorld)
```

Ok, this works in the way that there were no errors and server is registered, hence it is available in the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT registry. But what can I do with this? Some say you have to compile a instance and have a .dll or .exe file. WHat else do I have to do?

Comment: Well, first you need to know whether you have a 32-bit or 64-bit version of Python. You can test writing a VB script (.vbs file) with contents like `set obj = CreateObject("Python.TestServr")` You can try running the script with either 32-bit or 64-bit version of cscript.exe (in c:\windows\syswow64 or c:\windows\system32 respectively) If your sever is correctly registered it will work with one version but not the other. An important key is HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{7CC9F362-486D-11D1-BB48-0000E838A65F}\LocalServer32  (or maybe InProcServer32 ... IDK how Python does it)

Comment: If you didn't run the register part from an elevated prompt, instead of HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, look for HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes and then the rest.

Comment: I have 64-bit Python.  win32com.client.Dispatch("Python.TestServer") I seem to be able to run an object like this as well.

Comment: Looks like it's working then. I will risk stating the obvious here in that you don't start a COM server. Windows starts it. When the COM server needs to be used,then Windows starts it.  Sounds like it is working on your system. If you have Excel (64 bit version) on your machine, you could also try putting the code in my first comment into an Excel macro and see if it works as well. You could put a message box right after it: `MsgBox TypeName(obj)` and at that point you could use TaskManager to see if you can find a running instance of Python. (Close all instances of Python before this)

Comment: I might be what you are saying. To be honest I don't know when Python interprets the code. Does it interpret it when I register.  Thank you.

Comment: In Excel I get an error my hypothesis is that it is because I used a different conda environment to register the COM object. What interpreter does Excel use?

Comment: I asked another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66581340/running-com-objectpython-script-from-excel . Perhaps it could be clearer now.

Comment: Excel doesn't use any kind of Python interpreter. Excel uses their VBA engine which has been around forever. Did  you run the original Python script with elevated permissions or just as a regular local user?

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson I understand that Excel doesn't use Python. So my question is more what Python interpreter is used to interpret the Python code in the COM server? Or is it interpreted before hand? I tried running win32com.client.Dispatch("Python.TestServer")  in Python env that lack a library and the COM server did not work, because of it. Hence, I assume the code is interpreted later and I don't know which interpreter is used when I call it from Excel.

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson The VB script works with SYSWOW64/cscript.exe, but it doesn't with  system32, as you said it should be. MY excel is 64-bit, however it does not work in excel. Could it be the excel uses a 32 VB interpreter??

Comment: Well,that makes sense. SysWow64 is the 32-bit directory for windows on windows 64. It is the 32-bit windows on windows 64. So, Python is running it as 32-bit somehow. It not working on 64-bit is normal. You can track down further by looking up HKEY_CLASSSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{7CC9F362-486D-11D1-BB48-0000E838A65F}. That is the registry entry for your Python object. There will either be a LocalServer32 or InProcServer32 key (IDK, what Python does). That will point to the executable (.dll or .exe) that is run and command line arguments. You should be able to track it down from there.

Comment: Thanks, @JosephWillcoxson . I did not know SysWow64 is for 32-bit it is very counter-intuitive.

Comment: Interestingly I don't have an entry in  HKEY_CLASSSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{7CC9F362-486D-11D1-BB48-0000E838A65F}. There is an entry in  HKEY_CLASSSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\AppID\{7CC9F362-486D-11D1-BB48-0000E838A65F}, but there are no references to LocalServer32 or InProcServer32. As I read in the documentation Python is supposed to make both.

Comment: Did you ever answer whether you ran from an elevated prompt? If you didn't, then the clsid would be HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{7CC9F362-486D-11D1-BB48-0000E838A65F}. Or maybe for some reason that isn't the correct clsid at all? You can reverse lookup the clsid from the progid.

Comment: Yes, I ran it from elevated Prompt. The clsid is correct also, I did the reverse lookup. It is like I said the clsid is present in the AppID but not in the CLSID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I ran your example. The registry key for the server is at:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WOW6432Node\CLSID\{7CC9F362-486D-11D1-BB48-0000E838A65F}
```

It has two subkeys... one for LocalServer32 and one for InProcServer32

I created a simple VBA macro in Excel:

```
Sub d()
Set obj = CreateObject("Python.TestServer")

MsgBox obj.Hello("joe")
End Sub
```

Macro ran just fine. My version of Excel is 64-bit. I ran the macro and then fired up Task Manager while the message box was being displayed. I could see pythonw.exe running in the background.

The only difference between my python script and yours is probably the name and also that I added a line to print to make sure I was executing the function:

```
if __name__=='__main__':

    import win32com.server.register
    print("Going to register...")
    win32com.server.register.UseCommandLine(HelloWorld)
```

When I ran the 64-bit csript.exe test, it worked... as expected... when I ran the 32-bit version it failed.

I know why...sort of...
The registry entry for `InProcServer32` is `pythoncom36.dll`

That's no good. It is an incomplete path. I tried modifying the path variable on my shell to add to one of the 3 places where the DLL existed on my system, but it didn't work. Also, tried coding the path in the InProcServer32.  That didn't work.. kept saying it couldn't find the file.

I ran procmon, and then I observerved that it couldn't load vcruntime140.dll. Found the directory under python where those files were, and added to my path. It got further along. If I cared enough, I might try more. Eventually using procmon, I could find all the problems. But you can do that.

My simple solution was to rename the key `InProcServer32` for the CLSID to be _InProcServer32. How does that work? Well, the system can't find `InProcServer32` so it always uses `LocalServer32`--for 32-bit and 64-bit processes. If you need the speed of in process then you'd need to fix the problem by using procmon and being relentless until you solved all the File Not Found errors and such. But, if you don't need the speed of in process, then just using the LocalServer32 might solve the problem.

Caveats I'm using an Anaconda distro that my employer limits access to and I can only install it from the employee store. YMMV.

Comment: Thanks. There is still no entry for WOW6432Node\CLSID\{7CC9F362-486D-11D1-BB48-0000E838A65F}. I think it might be something with the installation, I just figured out I did not even do python Scripts/pywin32_postinstall.py -install, which is a necessity for registering COM objects. I have done this, however it is still not working. There was error when installing NOTE: PyWin32.chm can not be located, so has not been registered, I will be dealing with this now. btw, I also use conda.

Comment: Hey, it is working now. I don't know why the entry did not appear in WOW6432Node\CLSID\{7CC9F362-486D-11D1-BB48-0000E838A65F}, possibly I was searching for it the wrong way. Anyway, thank you so much for helping me. Now I am moving to get the RTD server to work.

Comment: Hey, I think my problems further on where connected to running my app as LocalServer and not as InProc. So I really want to get it to run this way. I have procmon now as you suggested, but I am not sure what to look for?

Comment: Well, you are going to want to filter out all processes except the one that is going to try and start the inproc server. You'll want to start procmon, set the filter, pause it, then clear messages. Then when you are ready to launch the inproc server, you'll want to start up procmon and then immediately stop when it fails. You can then search the logs ... start by finding where it is looking for the CLSID of your server.  Then, look for registry calls where it can't find a key. Search also for python37.dll or whatever yours is. See if there is a LoadLibrary fail.

Comment: Think: Why would COM fail? Answers are going to be 1) Can't find the ProgID in the registry. 2) Found ProgID but can't find CLSID. (Skip #1 if creating solely by CLSID). 3) Can't find InProcServer32 key or LocalServer32 key in CLSID entry, 4) Found entry but can't find actual file (bad path or non-existent), 5) Can't load DLL for InprocServer32 or can't load EXE for LocalServer32. For both of those cases, might fail because a dependent DLL is not available or installed correctly.... like maybe the Microsoft VC++ Runtime.

Comment: I think it is the answer 5). The entry for the InprocServer32 only has (Default) set as pythoncom37.dll. I think this is suspicious because it is not a complete path and because it is nothing specific to the actual COM object I registered.

Comment: You can search for pythoncom37.dll in the procmon log--you can save those logs too! Somewhere there will be a call to try and load it. Does it succeed or fail. You can change the registry entry to put the entire path in the InProcServer32 key. That might be one strategy to get you further along. After that, it might have problems finding the Microsoft runtime. You might need to install the Microsoft runtime if Python only has it locally. To find out what runtime Python is using, you might try running the Python IDE and then using procexp to look at what DLLs it has loaded to find MS runtime

Comment: It appears as the call to load pythoncom37.dll is successful, it finds it in C:\Windows\System32\pythoncom37.dll.