# Running COM object(Python script) from excel?

Tags: python, excel, vba, pywin32

Eventually I want to run RTD server and retrieve the data in excel. However I have problems with the basics. So, I am presenting you a reduced problem of running a COM object in Excel First.

```
class HelloWorld:
    _reg_clsid_ = "{7CC9F362-486D-11D1-BB48-0000E838A65F}"

    _reg_desc_ = "Python Test COM Server"

    _reg_progid_ = "Python.TestServer"


    _public_methods_ = ['Hello']

    _public_attrs_ = ['noCalls']

    _readonly_attrs_ = ['noCalls']

    def __init__(self):
        self.noCalls = 0

    def Hello(self):
        self.noCalls = self.noCalls + 1
        return "Hello World"


if __name__=='__main__':
    import win32com.server.register
    win32com.server.register.UseCommandLine(HelloWorld)
```

This is the basic code. It works fine the `Python.TestServer` is registered in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT and I can run it through Python.

```
o=win32com.client.Dispatch("Python.TestServer") 
o.Hello()
```

I tried to run through Excel(VB) as well.

```
Sub PythonTest()
    Set PythonUtils = CreateObject("Python.TestServer")
    r = PythonUtils.Hello()
    MsgBox r
End Sub
```

I get:

[image]

My hypotheses about what is wrong are:

- Something is not setup or enabled in Excel, although I have enabled Macros and ActiveX controls.
- You need to define a Python interpreter?

To elaborate on the second hypothesis. I don't exactly know what Python interpreter does the COM object use to execute commands, as I have several environments. Or is everything compiled when you register??

Comment: Easy way to check if the COM DLL is accessable by Excel: in the VB editor, go to Extras->References and see if you find your Python COM object there. If so, try adding it as a reference. You now can try to creat an instance with early binding. You now also have the option to use the Object Explorer (press F2) to find out how the COM interface exposes itself to VBA.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything for Excel. Is your Excel 32-bit or 64-bit? Did you run your original Python script as a regular user or did you run it with elevated privileges? That effects where the server is registered

Comment: @HelO'Ween Thanks for the tip. However My COM object is not there. So I tried to manually added, but than I found out I don't know where the .dll is. Keep in mind I have only executed the coded I posted. Perhaps I should have done something else to create the .dll?

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson Thanks for all the tips. My excel 64 bit, Python as well. I registered the server with admin access now there is no difference. I think it was registered with admin privileges before as it asked with a popup to Grant privileges.