# My registered COM object cannot be ran as InProc

Tags: com, pywin32, inproc

I am using pywin32 to register a COM object. The COM object get registered and it is avaialable in the registry editor at Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{B7B60366-B784-451F-BD6A-E7E733DB4E63}.

The problem is that the path in InProc32 includes only pythoncom37.dll. The only way can make the object work is to rename the inproc folder, so that it searches for LocalServer by default.

I believe several problems in the behavior of this object are connected to it not being ran as inproc, hence I really want to get it to run as inproc.

Any Ideas why this is the case? What can I do to change it?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "The only way can make the object work is to rename the inproc folder, so that it searches for LocalServer by default."? Plus, if you want it inproc, you can't use LocalServer.

Comment: The server modes are set when the object is built -- if it's been built as out-of-process, you cannot somehow run it in-process

Comment: @SimonMourier I am not an expert but in the registry editor there are entries for both LocalServer and InProcServer32, if I rename it to e.g. __InProcServer32 I can connect to the object via excel. I got the idea here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66550868/how-do-i-start-a-com-server-code-is-in-python

Comment: @M.M there are entries for both InProc32 and LocalServer.

Comment: A COM client can ask for the "default" context, or force inproc or outproc (comes from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtypesbase/ne-wtypesbase-clsctx. But indeed if you want to make sure only inproc is used you can delete (or rename) LocalServer32 key completely

Comment: Looked a little at it last time. Are you trying to run it from a 32-bit process? I believe we saw it was in the Wow6432Node part of registry. If so, since it is in process, you will only be able to create it in process from another 32 bit process. If you try from a 64-bit process it will fail.